# Loading File to TAdvMemo

Tags: c++builder, tms

Is there a way to load the content of a file to TAdvMemo not using the AcceptFile drag and drop option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most VCL-based memo controls (including third-party ones) have a `Lines.LoadFromFile` or something similar.

According to TMS's [website](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advmemo.asp?s=faq), `TAdvMemo` has a `Lines` property, which should be a `TStrings` descendant and therefore should support `LoadFromFile`. (See the FAQ page I linked to, specifically the question about seeing if the text is empty - it uses the `Lines` property.)

So it should be as easy as (Delphi code):

```
AdvMemo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('C:\Temp\YourFile.txt');
```

So, in C++ Builder it should be something like:

```
AdvMemo1->Lines->LoadFromFile("C:\\Temp\\YourFile.txt");
```